# User-customized background image in Launch Screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, splash-screen, launch-screen

Is it possible to add a **custom background image** to the Launch Screen (Splash Screen)?

If so, how can I do it in a **Flutter project**?

The idea is to have the application logo centered with the image chosen by the user on the back.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this package, It helps to generate splash screen in Flutter

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash